# Hidden Field as alternative to ViewState

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, hidden-field

I disabled view state on the entire website in web.config. I want to use Hidden Field in a page as alternative to viewstate.

I added a hidden field in my page as following:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="MyEmployeeId" runat="server" />
```

I then added the following property in my page:

```
    public int EmployeeId
    {
        get
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hdnEmployeeId.Value))
                return Convert.ToInt32(hdnEmployeeId.Value);                

            return -1;
        }
        set
        {
            hdnEmployeeId.Value = value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

I thought that this will work when I submit the page, but unexpectedly, the hidden field always returns empty string when IsPostBack is true. Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks for you help

Comment: Are you setting the value of the field somewhere. Please post enough code so we can have the full context/

Comment: At page init (for the first time) I set EmployeeId to some value. I also have a DDL in the page. When the selected index changes the page reloads so in Page Init (when is post back is true) I check if the selected value is different from the value in EmployeeId (this is a work around because selected index change wouldn't work when view state is false). however, at this point, EmployeeId has lost its value. I dont kknow how to fix this